# leftouter join in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, left-join, oracle9i

I have two tables initially in the application. They are as

```
user                       
------------------------      
user_id                      
column1                         
column2
..

Columnn
```

### user_account_info

```
user_id                   
account_number (can have multiple a/c number on single user_id)        
column1                      
column2          
..            
Columnn
```

---

the query is like

```
SELECT u.column1, uai.column1, uai.Keycolumn2
        FROM user u
        LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account_info uai on u.user_id  = uai.user_id
```

But later a new table user_account_map is added and user_account_info is changed

### user

```
user_id                 
column1                                        
column2             
..               
Columnn
```

### user_account_info

```
account_number (can have multiple a/c number on single user_id)                       
column1                  
column2               
..               
Columnn
```

### user_account_map

```
user_id                      
account_number (can have multiple a/c number on single user_id)                
column1              
column2
```

How to rewrite the query to match the output that of the previous query.
 Is it ok to write like

```
SELECT u.column1, uai.column1, uai.Keycolumn2
FROM user u
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account_map uam on u.user_id  = uam.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account_info uai on u.account_number  = uai.account_number
```

Comment: its urgent pls some clarify me

Comment: If you say "*it's urgent*" then someone is likely not to give you the solution deliberately.

Comment: Also if *its urgent* try to do a better job of explaining what it is your trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My query has the answer for itself. The query, for which i have asked, whether it is correct or not, is the correct one.
That is,

```
SELECT u.column1, uai.column1, uai.Keycolumn2
FROM user u
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account_map uam on u.user_id  = uam.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account_info uai on u.account_number  = uai.account_number
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can understand from your fuzzy question, I think that you only need to JOIN the three tables and since you have multiple `user_id` in the `table user_account_map` you will need to `GROUP BY` that field :

```
SELECT u.column1, uai.column1, uai.Keycolumn2, MAX(account_number) AS accNo
FROM user u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account_info uai USING(user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account_map uma  USING(user_id)
GROUP BY uma.user_id
```

Or otherwise simply JOIN the two tables containing `account_number` field with a double condition :

```
SELECT u.column1, uai.column1, uai.Keycolumn2
FROM user u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account_info uai USING(user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_account_map uma ON uma.account_number = uai.account_number AND uma.user_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you for the support. But i'm getting syntax error, when i tried both the above formats. Please help me solving the problem.